# change progress bar style in java for dynamicUI

Tags: android

i want change progressbar style in java for dynamicUI?before this i was set progressbarstyle on xml and there was style option but in java i cant find something like .setProgressbarstyle().

Comment: Can you explain a bit what exactly is your question? Totally vague description of what you want. Be precise.

Comment: how can i change progressbar style in java code?

Comment: Which java code, which progress bar? Are you trying to create your own progress bar or using some already implemented stuff?

Comment: yes i made progressbar like this in activity:

Comment: ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(this);

Comment: this is in circle style.i want change this to horizontal

Comment: my compiler geting error should i import something?

Comment: can not resolve symbol"Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal"

Comment: ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);

Comment: thank you it is helpful.i wish you put this in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using it like:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

These are the other styles, you can use:

> Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal
>
> Widget.ProgressBar.Small
>
> Widget.ProgressBar.Large
>
> Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse
>
> Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse
>
> Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse